# How to configure CakePHP 2.5.x for working with Ajax?

Tags: ajax, apache, .htaccess, cakephp

I'm working on localhost with xampp.
I installed the cakePHP application on C:\xampp\htdocs\mynewapp\ so I can access my CakePHP website via

```
http://localhost/mynewapp
```

I can access all my pages. It is working perfectly but I encounter some problems by making some Ajax calls.

This is my .htaccess configurations:
**C:\xampp\htdocs\mynewapp.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase    /linagal/app/
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**C:\xampp\htdocs\mynewapp\app.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**C:\xampp\htdocs\mynewapp\app\webroot.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mynewapp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I created a view **C:\xampp\htdocs\mynewapp\app\View\Photos\manage.ctp**. On this file, I make an Ajax call

```
$this->Js->sortable(array(
    'complete' => '$.post("/mynewapp/photos/reorder",
        $("#sortableitems").sortable("serialize"))'));
```

My problem is that I have to put *mynewapp* in the path given to $.post to make it works. I would like to write **$.post("/photos/reorder"; ...**

Any idea how i can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is that I have to put mynewapp in the path given to $.post

This has nothing to do with configuring CakePHP (or the webserver) to work with AJAX - it's a simple logic problem. There are two obvious ways to deal with what's describing.

### Use the router

Taken from the question, this is PHP code from a view file:

```
$this->Js->sortable(array(
    'complete' => '$.post("/mynewapp/photos/reorder",
        $("#sortableitems").sortable("serialize"))'));
```

As such, instead simply pass the url through the router first:

```
$url = $this->url('/photos/reorder');

$this->Js->sortable(array(
    'complete' => '$.post("' . $url . '",
        $("#sortableitems").sortable("serialize"))'));
```

This is in-keeping with writing Js using the Js helper but for anything beyond trivial js you may well find that that helper doesn't "Help" (in which case - don't use it).

### Use a js variable

Alternatively create a variable that can be used as the base url and prefix all urls with that. There are many ways to do that, one is:

```
<?php
// default layout file
$app = array(
    'root' => $this->url('/'),
    // add anything else the app's js might need here
);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script>
            var APP = <?= json_encode($app); ?>;
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    ...
```

And then modify the js helper call to be:

```
$this->Js->sortable(array(
'complete' => '$.post(APP.root + "photos/reorder",
    $("#sortableitems").sortable("serialize"))'));
```

Or similar.

Comment: I'm learning CakePHP and I'm not very familiar with some commands but it is coming :-)
Actually, I used the first solution (the router). I modified a little the solution :
    $url = $this->Html->url(array(
 "controller" => "photos",
 "action" => "reorder"
 ));
and it works perfectly!

Thanks for your help!